# What's the meaning of the place name 답십리(Dapsimni)? Is it related to Wangsimni?

Tags: place-names

The Wangsimni (왕십리) neighbourhood is apparently...

> ...related to a historical account dating from 14th century Korea. After establishing and becoming the first king of the Joseon dynasty, Yi Seong-gye presented the great Buddhist monk Muhak with the task of finding a site for the new capital. After searching for a suitable place, the monk stopped and saw an old farmer passing by on his ox. The farmer pointed toward the northwest and said to him, Wangsimni (往十里), literally meaning 'go ten more li (li = a unit measure that equals to one-third of a mile).' The startled Muhak went to the northwest as he was told and ended up at the southern foot of Mt. Bugak, where Gyeongbokgung now stands. This was how Hanyang (present-day Seoul) was born.

(From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wangsimni_Station)

답십리(Dapsimni) is similarly named, with Hanja (踏十里) that also refers to '10 ri'. Is the name of this neighbourhood related to Wangsimni?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chinese character "답" means to "step (on)" or "tread (on)". The name also was derived from the same legend.

According to the legend, the Buddhist monk stepped on this land before choosing the capital. You can read [this link](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=401545&cid=43722&categoryId=43722) for more information.

> 무학대사가 왕도를 정하려고 도성에서 10리 떨어진 이곳을 밟았다는 데서 유래됨.